# Data set of objects with properties

Tags: data-request, nlp

I am looking for data sets containing a list of objects or concepts as well as some of the properties.

Example 1:

```
#Format: [identifier][concept][feature][annotator1][annotator2][annotator3]
1   accordion   a_musical_instrument    all all all
2   accordion   associated_with_polkas  concept most    most
3   accordion   has_buttons all all all
4   accordion   has_keys    all all all
6   accordion   produces_music  all all most
7   accordion   requires_air    all all all
8   accordion   used_by_moving_bellows  all all all
9   accordion   worn_on_chest   all all all
10  airplane    crashes few some    few
11  airplane    flies   all all all
12  airplane    found_in_airports   most    all most
13  airplane    has_a_propeller some    some    some
14  airplane    has_engines all all most
15  airplane    has_wings   all all all
16  airplane    is_fast all some    some
18  airplane    made_of_metal   all most    most
19  airplane    requires_pilots all all most
20  airplane    used_for_passengers all some    some
21  airplane    used_for_transportation all most    most
22  airplane    used_for_travel all most    most
23  alligator   an_animal   all all no
24  alligator   a_reptile   all all all
25  alligator   eats_people most    few few
26  alligator   has_a_mouth all all all
27  alligator   has_a_tail  all all all
28  alligator   has_jaws    all all all
29  alligator   has_scales  all all all
30  alligator   has_teeth   all all all
32  alligator   is_green    most    some    some
33  alligator   is_long all some    some
35  alligator   lives_in_Florida    most    some    some
37  alligator   lives_in_water  all all some
38  alligator   swims   all all most
```

Example 2:

- 1 row = 1 object (aka concept)
- 1 row = 1 property (aka feature)
- cell value: indicate how frequently the object has the property. 0 = never, 1 = always.

[image]

---

So far I have found:

1. [herbelot_iwcs13_data.txt](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~ah433/material/herbelot_iwcs13_data.txt) 
   (Aurelie Herbelot. 2013. What is in a text, what isn’t, and what this has to do with lexical semantics. In Proceedings of the Tenth International Conference on Computational Semantics (IWCS2013), Potsdam, Germany.)
2. [mcrae-quantified-majority.txt](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~ah433/mcrae-quantified-majority.txt) (
   Aurelie Herbelot and Eva Maria Vecchi. 2015. From concepts to models: some issues in quantifying feature norms. Linguistic Issues in Language Technology. To appear.)

Comment: Isn't this literally what wikidata.org does?